# Losing Wifi Connection (Ubuntu 22.04) on ASRock ION 3D and 5gz not showing

Tags: 20.04, wireless

newbie question...

Just tried to resurrect an old box I have here, wanted to try out Ubuntu etc..

Its an ASRock ION 3D .. I dunno if its too old or not.. 2Ghz Ram.
Specs are here: https://www.asrock.com/nettop/Intel/ION%203D%20Series/index.asp?cat=

But anyway.. Ubuntu 20.04 installed fine.. little slow but functional.
Problem is two fold:

1. It will only show the 2.4Ghz wifi available from my router (Asus Zenwifi AX Xt8) and doesn't show the 5Ghz. So will only connect to the 2.4Ghz
2. Keeps dropping the 2.4Ghz. Even when I do get on the 2.4Ghz it only stays connected for a short while before losing it..

I had this machine with windows 7 on it and the wifi was workin ok. So I don't think its a hardware issue.

Not sure what to do with this to investigate so would appreciate some suggestions.

If possible I'd prefer to connect to the 5Ghz really...

Thanks